# Making buttons that look like tabs in android

Tags: android, button, tabs

I want this kind of look. They don't seem like `tabs` so I believe they are buttons.

[image]

I am able to acheive the similar type with `toggle button` by keeping a selector in drawable.

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_selector"    
    android:textOn=" Button1    Button2"
    android:textOff=" Button1   Button2" />
```

But they have only two values and by clicking on the selected tab gets the other selected and the present one unselected. But I want exactly like tab. So can someone please help me achieve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use toggle button , take four buttons and use selector in drawable.

Comment: @ManojPal Thanks, but those don't give look like the above corner shapes and all. That too by selecting one button the button selected before should get normal color again.

Comment: its little bit tricky , you can use corner shape images as a background in buttons and add a condition that if one button is selected change other button background as normal. and it will give feel like tab.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to create selector for all button and use `RadioGroup` with selector background and null button..

Follow @Andru answer for create Selector..

Below is RadioGroup code.

```
    <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rdogrp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn1Selector"
        android:button="@null"
        android:checked="true"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn2Selector"
        android:button="@null"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn3Selector"
        android:button="@null"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/btn4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn4Selector"
        android:button="@null"
        android:gravity="center" />
</RadioGroup>
```

here is sample code for `btn1Selector.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn1_selected" android:state_checked="true"  />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn1_normal" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this, instead of toggle button use normal buttons.

if "Data" button clicked do like this

```
data(View v)
 {
  databtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image1);
  w_chartbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image2);
  H_chartbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image2);
 }
```

if "H-chart" button clicked

```
 H_chart(View v)
 {
  databtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image2);
  w_chartbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image2);
  H_chartbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image1);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use simple button instead of toogle button. And set background like this:

I am giving example for 1 button:

```
 android:background="@drawable/data_button_select_state"
```

And add a xml file in your 'drawable' folder named data_button_select_state:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/data_image_selected_state"
      android:state_selected="true" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/data_image_selected_state"
      android:state_pressed="true" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/data_image_without_selected" />
</selector>
```

Now add code in java file like this:

when data button clicked:

```
  data_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            data_button.setActivated(true);
            H_chart_button.setActivated(false);
                            w_chart_button.setActivated(false);
                            hc_chart_button.setActivated(false);

        }
    });
```

change other button like this as well. This will might help you...