# Fixed Tab inside fixed tab in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-tabs, android-tabactivity

i want add tabs inside tab like below:

```
 ----------------------
|Tab 1 | Tab 2 | tab 3 |
-----------------------
| Sub tab 1 | Sub tab 2|
 ----------------------
```

Each `Parent tab` has two `sub tab`. I am using fragment to display Parent tab(`Action Bar tab`).

I tried this by implementing fragment replace but android doesn't support `nested fragment` (except  17+). How can i get this done.Please help me out to solve this.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
    android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="#33b5e5"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may been able to do that if the sub tabs are views and not fragments. Usign TabHost, TabWidget, a FrameLayout with id "@android:id/tabcontent" with the different tabs inside.

Comment: could you please explain this?

Answer (score 0):

You can disguise `RadioButton` to look like tabs and add as many layers as you want. This offers even higher flexibility in looks than the android inbuilt version. The `RadioGroup` ensures that only 1 is selected at a time.
Check out the accepted answer [Making buttons that look like tabs in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540111/making-buttons-that-look-like-tabs-in-android) for implementation.

Comment: could you please explain this?

Comment: basic functionality of tab to have one item selected at a time and using that info you can load content on the rest of the page.

Comment: you want me to put radio button inside fragment?

Comment: How the fragment XML will look like?

Comment: Don't use fragment to display parent tab. Add two layers of radio groups one after the other. Fetch value from first layer to update second layer and fetch value from second layer to do what you want with rest of the page. The radio button is just an image and hence can be changed to active/inactive image of tab button. There are lot of examples on how to do it including the one i linked.

Comment: could please give some other links related to this.

Comment: http://www.phonesdevelopers.com/1772557/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540111/making-buttons-that-look-like-tabs-in-android will put you in the right direction i hope.