# I want to devleope dynamic android screen like this

Tags: android, material-design

I want to develope screen like the below..which contains two tabs with right alignment!

actually it's the dynamic screen and top part should be fixed with two tabs when ever they click the tabs it's different fragment. please suggest me the best way.

Comment: if there are only two fragments then you can replace the fragments on button click event

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewPager for this.

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/vpPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Here is a [link](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter) for your reference.
Design two different layout files and switch them on Tabchange.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use **RadioGroup to act like tabs** with fragments

like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17541555/3020568

OR you can use **PagerSlidingTabStrip** library and customize it like the way you want

https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip